# Semantics of evaluating lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda

Lets say I have the following:

```
class A 
{
  T x;
  Func<T> f;

  A() 
  {
    f = () => x;
  }

  void SetX(T blah)
  {
    x = blah;
  }
}
```

Is it always true that `f()` == `x`.

i.e. after a call to `SetX(y)`, is it true that `f()` == `x` == `y`?

(Please note if this is different for value vs reference types)

More broadly, is there some information I can read (or can be placed in an answer) on whether lambda arguments either are evaluated at the creation of a lambda or when the lambda is executed? I could just test these cases but I would like some reading material so I understand how it works so I'm less likely to have any future gotchas.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Your "more broadly" is an off-topic question (asking for off-site resources). Your initial question is trivially satisfied simply by running the code and seeing what happens.

Comment: @kristianp: I don't understand your comment. First of all, the default accessibility for a class member is `private`, so not having the accessibility declared at all is the same as declaring it `private`. But secondly, the class name is `A`, so the method named `A()` is a constructor and so can only be executed once. The code example could have been more clear, but there's nothing there that indicates the value of `f` could change after the object is created. Nor would that really matter to the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "lambda arguments" (this lambda has no parameters), you probably mean "variables captured by the lambda", and you are asking whether variables are captured by value (so it remembers the value at the time of creation of the lambda) or by reference (so it refers to the value of the variable at the time the lambda is run).

In this case, `x` is an instance variable, so accessing `x` implicitly means `this.x`, so the "local variable" that the lambda really captures is `this` (the implicit `this` inside the constructor of `A`). C# closures capture variables by reference (and this is true for all types of variables), but in this case, since `this` is not assignable, it makes no difference if it is captured by value or by reference.